# Problem using Mailjet's contactdata/contactID API endpoint

Tags: javascript, api, put, mailjet

I work for few days on a way to be able to update Mailjet contact properties using Google Apps Script, and the Mailjet API endpoint always returns an error 400, no matter what I put in the data. Even using cURL and following the Mailjet API example, it fails with error 400. I really don't know what to do to get rid of this and be able to go further !...

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl -s -X PUT --user "publicKey-xxxx:secretKey-yyyy" https://api.mailjet.com/v3/REST/contactdata/38398922 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "Data" : [{ "Name" : "genre", "Value" : "Homme" }, { "Name" : "age", "Value" : "20" }] }'
```

Response :

```
{ "ErrorInfo" : "", "ErrorMessage" : "Invalid json input: property \"\" not found at stream position 5", "StatusCode" : 400
```

Does anyone already face this issue and found a way to get this error resolved ? I really think this API call does not work, at all, on Mailjet side..

Thanks !
Kind regards,

Christophe

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but for documentations sake...
I've been facing this promlem as well (on Windows using the curl commandline tool).

In my case I had to subsitute single quotes with double ones and within the JSON I had to escape the double quotes. In your case like so:

```
curl -s -X PUT --user "publicKey-xxxx:secretKey-yyyy" https://api.mailjet.com/v3/REST/contactdata/38398922 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"Data\" : [{ \"Name\" : \"genre\", \"Value\" : \"Homme\" }, { \"Name\" : \"age\", \"Value\" : \"20\" }] }"
```

Give it a try...

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and found that I needed to add the "Content-Type" header as "application/json" to the request